# Fill char *array from 0 to x

Tags: c, arrays, char

i have a problem with a char *array in c (gcc linux)

on debian it works, but on another systems (yocto,raspbian) come a segmentation fault

The working Code in Debian:

```
char *myarray;
for (i=0;i<999;i++){
printf(myarray, "%i", i);
//do something with string to compare in file
}
```

But this Code fault on another Systems, i have tried to make a Array:

```
char *myarray[999]={"0","1","2"};
for (i=0;i<999;i++){
    //do something with string[i] to compare in file
}
```

This Code also works but i dont like to fill a array from hand to "999"

I haven't found a method to make a `char *string[arr]` from "0"-"999" in a loop

Comment: If your first code works in Debian, that is purely accidental. You allocate a pointer to something but never initialize it; then you access its contents. Also, the syntax of that `printf` line is really weird. Are you sure this is your "working code"?

Comment: @RadLexus as pointed out by ameyCU below, he means (or should mean) sprintf(). But yeah, the whole thing's goofy.

Comment: That question is used as a `STOP! Look and Listen` in the reopen queue. I respectfully disagree. One should be able to post an answer showing good code to the poor guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , you can use [`sprintf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)-

```
char *array[1000];
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
   array[i]=malloc(10*sizeof(**array));    //allocate memory to pointer
   if(array[i]!=NULL){                     //check return of malloc
      sprintf(array[i],"%d",i);            
   }
}
```

*Note*- Just remember to `free` the allocated memory.

Comment: Where's that malloc() arg come from? Seems like malloc(4) would handle "999" (plus terminating '\0').

Comment: @JohnForkosh Just allocating little bit more memory . It is just equal to `10` bytes .

Comment: `sizeof( **array )` is `sizeof( char )` is `1` is needless obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

It's very unclear what you're after.

If you want to build an array holding the strings "0" through "999", you can do it using `snprintf()`:

```
char array[1000][4]; /* Wastes some space, but not a great deal. */
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  snprintf(array[i], sizeof array[i], "%d", i);
```

then you can print e.g. `452` like so:

```
printf("452 is %s\n", array[452]);
```